# Unable to remove rundeck in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation, rundeck

I installed rundeck on my ubuntu server, now I am unable to remove rundeck from my server, getting error

```
root@rundeck:~# apt autoremove rundeck -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rundeck
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 295 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 76559 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rundeck (4.0.0.20220322-1) ...
Failed to stop rundeckd.service: Unit rundeckd.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package rundeck (--remove):
 installed rundeck package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 5
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rundeck
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@rundeck:~# 


This is the o/p for apt-get install rundeck

root@rundeck:~# apt-get install rundeck 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
rundeck is already the newest version (4.0.0.20220322-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@rundeck:~#
```

I removed rundeck files from /etc ,/var/log , /var/lib

Answer (score 0):

`autoremove` is not for removing installed packages.

> autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages

Use `apt remove rundeck` or to remove configuration file as well use: `apt purge rundeck`.

then confirm with `dpkg -l|grep rundeck` if the lackage is listed, it is not fully removed.

You can also purge a package with `dpkg -P rundeck`, but this is dangerous as dpkg might not honor all the dependencies. But its still am option.

Comment: Hi @Ron I tried your suggestions still getting the same result

Comment: do you get the same errors?? if so, try `apt install --reintall rundeck`, then try to remove it again. If there are errors, you would obviously try to solve those, else the uninstall is not going to be clean.